# Same object in multiple webservices result in duplicate classes

Tags: c#, java, web-services

We have several .Net webservices that we use a java client for. Each webservice has it's own namespace, but they all use a lot off common classes. When these are exposed as WSDLs, then generated into Java code, we get a lot of duplicates in Java of the same .Net classes.

Is there a way in .Net to define a set of WebService objects to be exported under a shared namespace (in XML)? Or can we when we use wsimport in Java to generate just one instance of each duplicate class?

Answer (score 0):

From service side, one of the option could be to have specially crafted single WSDL describing all services. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163819.aspx) for how to do it (applicable for asmx services).

On side note, for .NET clients, its quite simple to use wsdl tool with [sharetypes](http://www.freddes.se/2009/02/16/multiple-web-service-references-sharing-types/) options to have common types generated once and re-used among multiple service proxies. Hopefully, similar tools/options perhaps exist at java client side.

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` option of [wsimport](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) allows you to override the namespace specified in the WSDL to a package that you specify. If you specify the same package for each WSDL you'll only end up with one instance of each class.